# Handling "flags" types in telegram's TL schema language

Tags: python, api, telegram

I wrote a tl parser so can now use the latest layer (53). But I am unsure how to handle "flags" types. They are only mentioned in the tl docs but not defined (as far as I can tell) at the bottom of the page here: [link](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/TL-formal).

For example, when a method returns a 'message' type it should look like this:
`message#c09be45f flags:# out:flags.1?true mentioned:flags.4?true media_unread:flags.5?true silent:flags.13?true post:flags.14?true id:int from_id:flags.8?int to_id:Peer fwd_from:flags.2?MessageFwdHeader via_bot_id:flags.11?int reply_to_msg_id:flags.3?int date:int message:string media:flags.9?MessageMedia reply_markup:flags.6?ReplyMarkup entities:flags.7?Vector<MessageEntity> views:flags.10?int edit_date:flags.15?int = Message;`

If I understand correctly each flag is a bit set in some variable, right?

My parser breaks out the 'message' type like this:

> ```
>      id: -1063525281
>      params:
>              name: flags
>              type:
>                      name: out
>                      bit: 1
>                      type: true
>
>                      name: mentioned
>                      bit: 4
>                      type: true
>
>                      name: media_unread
>                      bit: 5
>                      type: true
>
>                      name: silent
>                      bit: 13
>                      type: true
>
>                      name: post
>                      bit: 14
>                      type: true
>
>                      name: from_id
>                      bit: 8
>                      type: int
>
>                      name: fwd_from
>                      bit: 2
>                      type: MessageFwdHeader
>
>                      name: via_bot_id
>                      bit: 11
>                      type: int
>
>                      name: reply_to_msg_id
>                      bit: 3
>                      type: int
>
>                      name: media
>                      bit: 9
>                      type: MessageMedia
>
>                      name: reply_markup
>                      bit: 6
>                      type: ReplyMarkup
>
>                      name: entities
>                      bit: 7
>                      type: Vector<MessageEntity>
>
>                      name: views
>                      bit: 10
>                      type: int
>
>                      name: edit_date
>                      bit: 15
>                      type: int
>
>              name: id
>              type: int
>
>              name: to_id
>              type: Peer
>
>              name: date
>              type: int
>
>              name: message
>              type: string
>
>      predicate: message
>      type: Message
> ```

But if the flags are bits in some variable, which variable?

Related: is tl based on a formal, standardized language spec or was it created specifically for telegram? I ask because if it is a subset of a formal language (like yaml) it might be better to use an already known parser for tl instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: TL is specifically designed for Telegram.

Comment: yes it's specifically designed for Telegram and the documentation is not mature yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if the flags are bits in some variable, which variable?

```
Message#c09be45f flags:# out:flags.1?true mentioned:flags.4?true media_unread:flags.5?true silent:flags.13?true post:flags.14?true id:int from_id:flags.8?int to_id:Peer fwd_from:flags.2?MessageFwdHeader via_bot_id:flags.11?int reply_to_msg_id:flags.3?int date:int message:string media:flags.9?MessageMedia reply_markup:flags.6?ReplyMarkup entities:flags.7?Vector<MessageEntity> views:flags.10?int edit_date:flags.15?int = Message;
```

**Example**: `flags:# out:flags.1?true`

Decoding Flags: BinaryAND(flags, 2^ix) === 2^ix --> this will help you determine if a field is included or not

**flags** = The value if the `flags` field, this is usually the first field for objects with flags

ix == flag index, this is a number that indicates flag position, e.g. `out:flags.1?true` here out is the field in flag position 1, and the type is true

For the example above `out` will have a value of `true` if `BAND(flags,2^N) == 2^N` otherwise, `out` field is ignored

**Code - Message Encoding (Elixir)**

```
def encode(%Message{} = x), do: <<95, 228, 155, 192, encode(:Int, x.flags)::binary, enc_f(:True, x.out, x.flags, 2)::binary, enc_f(:True, x.mentioned, x.flags, 16)::binary, enc_f(:True, x.media_unread, x.flags, 32)::binary, enc_f(:True, x.silent, x.flags, 8192)::binary, enc_f(:True, x.post, x.flags, 16384)::binary, encode(:Int, x.id)::binary, enc_f(:Int, x.from_id, x.flags, 256)::binary, encode(x.to_id)::binary, enc_f(x.fwd_from, x.flags, 4)::binary, enc_f(:Int, x.via_bot_id, x.flags, 2048)::binary, enc_f(:Int, x.reply_to_msg_id, x.flags, 8)::binary, encode(:Int, x.date)::binary, encode(:String, x.message)::binary, enc_f(x.media, x.flags, 512)::binary, enc_f(x.reply_markup, x.flags, 64)::binary, enc_vf(x.entities, x.flags, 128)::binary, enc_f(:Int, x.views, x.flags, 1024)::binary, enc_f(:Int, x.edit_date, x.flags, 32768)::binary>>
```

**Code - Message Decode (Elixir)**

```
  def decode(<<95, 228, 155, 192, bin::binary>>) do
    {flags, bin} = decode(:Int, bin)
    {out, bin} = decode(:True, bin, flags, 2) # 1
    {mentioned, bin} = decode(:True, bin, flags, 16) # 4
    {media_unread, bin} = decode(:True, bin, flags, 32) # 5
    {silent, bin} = decode(:True, bin, flags, 8192) # 13
    {post, bin} = decode(:True, bin, flags, 16384) # 14
    {id, bin} = decode(:Int, bin)
    {from_id, bin} = decode(:Int, bin, flags, 256) # 8
    {to_id, bin} = decode(bin)
    {fwd_from, bin} = decode(bin, flags, 4) # 2
    {via_bot_id, bin} = decode(:Int, bin, flags, 2048) # 11
    {reply_to_msg_id, bin} = decode(:Int, bin, flags, 8) # 3
    {date, bin} = decode(:Int, bin)
    {message, bin} = decode(:String, bin)
    {media, bin} = decode(bin, flags, 512) # 9
    {reply_markup, bin} = decode(bin, flags, 64) # 6
    {entities, bin} = decode([:MessageEntity], bin, flags, 128) # 7
    {views, bin} = decode(:Int, bin, flags, 1024) # 10
    {edit_date, bin} = decode(:Int, bin, flags, 32768) # 15
    {%Message{flags: flags, out: out, mentioned: mentioned, media_unread: media_unread, silent: silent, post: post, id: id, from_id: from_id, to_id: to_id, fwd_from: fwd_from, via_bot_id: via_bot_id, reply_to_msg_id: reply_to_msg_id, date: date, message: message, media: media, reply_markup: reply_markup, entities: entities, views: views, edit_date: edit_date}, bin}
  end

#5 == 2^5 == 32
#4 == 2^4 == 16
```

so basically `N == 2^N, where N == ix`

Comment: @kenny-cason if you need help **encoding** the flags as well, make a new question on that too

Comment: So, are you saying there is a variable called `flags` returned by the server for the `message` type? If so what type is `flags`, **integer**? In your example above, is `out` always returned by the server or only if the bit for that flag is set? What about objects that have a mandatory `flags:int` field but also have these optional flags, how do you tell them apart?

Comment: yes it is an integer, it is usually in the first position

Comment: a field is only included if its flag returns true. it is indeed a very efficient packing scheme

Comment: flags:# is always mandatory but it could be 0 indicating that all optional fields are ignored or not present

Comment: please understand that ```flags:#``` is the flag definition, you can use the ```flags.N?xxx``` to determine if the received bytes contains a particular field, check if ```BAND(flags,N^2) === true```

Comment: Your example above works for `ix=1`, which seems to be a special case since 1 raised to any power is still 1. But what if `ix=4`? Then `ix^2=16=00010000`, which is position 5 not 4. If instead you use `2^(ix-1)` then if `ix=4` then `2^(4-1)=2^3=8=00001000`, which **is** position 4. Please correct me if I am not thinking about this properly.

Comment: @KennyCason see i have edited above to include my full Message Encoder and Decoder (in Elixir) hope it helps

Comment: i think it is just ```ix = 4 then 2^4 = 16``` for flags.4?xxx @KennyCason

Comment: Thanks, that's not what I expected but ok. Do the parameters have to be encoded/decoded in a specific order? In other words, can I decode all the optional flagged parameters first or must they be in the order given: `flags`, `out`, `mentioned`, `media_unread`, etc. Lists in Python are not guaranteed to be in any order.

Comment: yes it is expected. because you are building up a byte array or you are decoding a byte array, so the format of the fields matters as defined by the TL schema

Comment: @KennyCason not familiar with Python, but you are building up a byte sequence and it must be in order, ignored flags are not included at all

Comment: FYI: My mistake, Python lists have guaranteed order. I'll have to modify my logic to take that into account.

Comment: If a flagged parameter, like `out` above, is of type `true` but that bit is not set, should decode evaluate to `out=false` or just ignore that parameter?

Comment: in decoding yes, it would be equivalent to false (or even ignored). either should equate to same in your client code

Comment: I just realized my confusion with this. In your first post you state the equation is `ix^2`, but later state it as `2^ix`. I was using the first equation when the correct answer is the second. I'm sure it was simply a typo on your part.