# Telegram API Layer54 C# - Questions

Tags: c#, telegram

I'm trying to write a simple client for Telegram in C# exploiting their API layer 54.

I'm following the scheme here: https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/master/Telegram/SourceFiles/mtproto/scheme.tl

I've started by following the previous work made by Sochix: https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp, but this implementation refers to API Layer 23 and basically the parsing of nearly all the objects are different.

Now, since there is no documentation ( or at least I couldn't find anything online ) about the layer 54 and the doc on the main site is not so good, I've a couple of questions:

1- Using the InitConnection method I specify through the "invokeWithLayer" request that I will use the Layer 54. Given that, I expect that all the following answers return objects respecting the code specified in the Layer 54 scheme, however sometimes happen that Telegram server answers me with object's code of old API layer, somebody have an idea on why this happen?

2- Regarding the flagged objects such as User/Message etc..., I've found this old answer [Handling "flags" types in telegram's TL schema language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903321/handling-flags-types-in-telegrams-tl-schema-language), but is there an official documentation on how to decode and encode this kind of objects? Moreover, following the answer proposed by Charles, shouldn't be BAND(flags,1^2) == flags == true in order to check if a flagged field has been sent or not?

3- During the developing of such a library I've to make lots of tests in order to understand if my code works correctly or not, how can I avoid the "Too many requests" error? I've tried to reuse the session.dat created by TLSharp, but seems that it doesn't work.

Thank you very much

Comment: what parts of the responses are in old API Layer?

Comment: Hey Charles, glad to see you! :-) 
I've pasted the error on the formula (2^N obviously and not 1^2 ), what I meant was if the check should be BAND(flags,2^N) === flags and not BAND(flags,2^N) === true. 
The sentCode object and also the auth.Authroization object are from older layer, also this seems to happen randomly...

Comment: Well, sentCode and auth.Authorization are for sure different: 

auth.sentCode#2215bcbd for Layer 2  

auth.sentCode#5e002502 Layer 54

As said sometimes it replies me with Layer 2 code, other times with Layer 54 code...Could be the dc?

Comment: @3 Why are you getting "too many requests" error?

Comment: point 2) of your question is on flags...

Comment: yup, sorry, typo! Any idea regarding point 1 and 3? :-)

Comment: >Telegram server answers me with object's code of old API layer 

can you give an example of this?

Comment: I sent the request: **auth.sendCode#86aef0ec** that is supposed to return a **auth.sentCode#5e002502** following the scheme of Layer 54, but it instead returns the **auth.sentCode#2215bcbd** from Layer 2.

Comment: before executing actual layer-54 commands, you need  to confirm that your session is correctly setup for layer-54 and that you are subsequently sending requests under that layer-54 session key

Comment: how can I confirm this? I mean, in the doc: https://core.telegram.org/api/invoking, they say that after invoking InitConnection you are done

Comment: This is my init + sendcode on layer-53 *(in Elixir)*, and it works all the time:  `msg = TL.invokewithlayer(layer, TL.initconnection(app_id, device_model, system_version, app_version, lang_code, TL.auth_sendcode(0, nil, s.mobile, s.mobile, app_id, app_hash)))` I have not tried this on layer 54, but it should work regardsless

Comment: Uhm, ok, I think that my C# code should be equivalent to yours. 
I will check it, thanks!

Comment: :) my code is not c#.... its Elixir

Comment: Yeah, I saw. I meant that my C# code should be equivalent to your Elixir code! Now I'm working on it, thanks for the support man! :-)

Comment: I've had similar issues with the server responding in a different layer format than what I sent. If you figure out the problem please post it here. As it is I decided to wrap **every** method in invokeWithLayer until I figure out a better way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

I will post answers here, maybe they will be useful in future to somebody:

1) I've discovered that the problem was related to a wrong DC configured inside the Session.cs ( TLSharp library ).

2) As Charles point out BinAND(flag,2^N) = 2^N.

Example: when we read the flags: # field ( an int32 ) from an object
         we have:

```
flag: 0000 0010 0001 0011
```

if we want to know if the flag self:flags.10?true is setted or not we must test the bit 10 inside the flag int32, so:

```
0000111000010011 &
0000010000000000 =
------------------
0000010000000000 -> FLAG SETTED!
```

[WARNING] if the flag is setted and the type of the flag is ?true, you DON'T have to read the _true code from the binary stream, while if it is another type such as 'int' you are supposed to read its value from the stream.

3) This error is automatically handled by the current implementation of the TLSharp library in the file MTProtoSender.cs. When you receive a "FLOOD_WAIT" error you have to wait for X second as the Telegram documentation report:

**FLOOD_WAIT_X: A wait of X seconds is required (where X is a number)**

After a sleep of X seconds you can return to make RPC to Telegram server. However, after lot of request X become around 20h, and this is a problem...

Answer (score 0):

Check newsest version of [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp), it supports layer 53. And have no problems with decoding.